# Armar un array de objetos extrayendo datos de objetos que estan en otro array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Buen dia,

Tengo el siguiente array de ventas las cuales consulto en una BD de firebase, las cuales dentro de la clave productos tienen los productos de la venta en  si

```
var ventas = [
  {
    fecha:"2022-05-02",
    cliente:"Juan Perez",
    productos:[
      {nombre:"Manzana",cantidad:5,valor:20},
      {nombre:"Pera", cantidad:3, valor:10},
      {nombre:"Piña", cantidad:8, valor:15}
    ]
  },
  {
    fecha:"2022-07-04",
    cliente:"Amanda Gonzales",
    productos:[
      {nombre:"Mango",cantidad:4, valor:20},
      {nombre:"Pera", cantidad:2, valor:10}
    ]
  },
  {
    fecha:"2022-02-01",
    cliente:"Maria Perez",
    productos:[
      {nombre:"Piña",cantidad:1, valor:18},
      {nombre:"Mango", cantidad:5, valor:15},
      {nombre:"Manzana",cantidad:6, valor:12},
    ]
  },  
]
```

Un cliente puede tener 1 o varios productos los cuales siempre tienen el mismo nombre, lo que necesito es armar el siguiente array de objetos el cual me muestre los totales de los productos, para el ejemplo anterior seria

```
var totales = [
    {nombre:"Manzana", cantidad: 11, valor:32}
    {nombre:"Pera", cantidad: 5, valor:22},
    {nombre:"Piña", cantidad: 9, valor:33},
    {nombre:"Mango", cantidad: 9, valor:35},
]
```

como yo lo he hecho es declarar un array "temporal" que me guarde los productos de todas las ventas,

luego con un forEach iterar todas los posiciones de **ventas** para luego con un forEach anidado iterar todas las posiciones de **productos** y hacer push de cada objeto de producto en el array **temporal**

luego al terminar eso, tendria que declarar el array **totales**

luego tendria que recorrer el array **temporal** con otro forEach, luego otro forEach anidado que revise si el objeto iterado de **temporal** esta en **totales**, algo asi como if(temporal.nombre == totales.nombre)
y asi ir sumando

suena enredado pero asi lo entiendo yo, he leido algo sobre includes, pero no he dado con esto, hay alguna manera de hacerlo mas sencillo?

gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

este código es eficiente y funciona bien, espero que te sirva.

```
function addProducts(ventas){
    let productos = {};
    //recorres todas las ventas
    ventas.forEach((venta) => {
        //compruebas que ventas esté bien definido (esto puedes quitarlo)
        if(Array.isArray(venta.productos)){
            //recorres los productos
            venta.productos.forEach((p) => {
                //para cada producto lo metes es un objeto con su nombre como clave
                // {
                //  "Manzana":{nombre:"Manzana",cantidad:5,valor:20},
                //}
                // y si ya existe ese elemento manzana, entonces le sumas la cantidad y el valor
                if (!productos[p.nombre]) productos[p.nombre]={...p};
                else{
                    productos[p.nombre].cantidad+=p.cantidad;
                    productos[p.nombre].valor+=p.valor;
                }
            });
        }
    })
    //retornas un vector con los valores de las variables que has guardado
    return  Object.values(productos);
}
```

Comment: super bien!! solo que el valor no lo muestra correctamente, una pregunta, si yo quisiera saber el total recaudado de las ventas en cada uno de los productos, por ejemplo en la manzana seria en la primera venta 5unds*20 + en la tercera venta 11unds*32 daria el total vendido en dinero de 452 para manzanas, tendria que agregar segun entiendo yo esto productos[p.nombre].valor+=(p.cantidad*p.valor); debajo de donde colocaste productos[p.nombre].cantidad+=p.cantidad; pero resulta que suma mal, alguna idea?

Comment: Perdona, sí lo muestra mal porque pensé que el valor es el total, ahora lo cambio en código para que no sea el total si no el valor por unidad, a parte de eso también hay que cambiar la línea de "if (!productos[p.nombre]) productos[p.nombre]={...p};" para sacar el valor total, posiblemente por eso te funciona mal

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que no lo muestra correctamente? ¿el valor es por unidad o por compra? porque parece que estás intentando calcularlo como si fuera por unidad pero si divides por ejemplo el valor de los mangos entre su cantidad da la sospechosa cantidad constante de 5, lo cual me da a entender que el valor es el precio por compra no por unidad. ¿Puedes comprobarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Si, podes crear una funcion que cree un array con los productos unicos de todas las ventas y que devuelva ese array, como dijiste hay que hacer una doble iteracion, una sobre las ventas y otro sobre el arreglo "productos" de cada venta:

```
function addProducts(){
    let products = [];
    ventas.forEach((venta) => {
        for(let i=0;i<venta.productos.length;i++) 
        if(!products.includes(venta.productos[i].nombre)) 
        products.push(venta.productos[i].nombre)
        // uso de include para saber si el array products ya tiene el producto que estamos iterando y si no esta, lo agrega      
    })
    return products;
}

console.log(addProducts())
```

Si hay algun cambio en ventas solo hay que volver a llamar a la funcion y recuperar el valor del array devuelto para actualizarlo, y podemos trabajar con el como queramos:

```
let arrayProductos = addProducts();
```

en este caso solo guarde en el arreglo los nombres de los productos, pero podes guardar todo el objeto en si borrando los .nombre que hay en la funcion